# Eclipse- modified source lines ignored when debugging Tomcat application from within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am having some issues (confusion) when attempting to debug a Tomcat application from within Eclipse.  I have setup my project so that I can invoke Tomcat v7 from within Eclipse so that I can Debug my application on the Server.  My project is a Maven project, and normally use a Maven Build to compile the project (outside of Eclipse), which results in a .war file that gets deployed into Tomcat (which I have installed into a directory).

When I changed some of the source code from within Eclipse, and attempted a "Debug on Server.." it seems the changed source lines are not recognized (previous to attempting to changing any java source code, all normal debug operations worked fine).  The Debugger loads the class file, but it as if the Source and ByteCode are now out of sync.  I do not understand when I execute my project on Tomcat Server (and what do they mean by this, a pseudo Tomcat Server tied directly to Eclipse?) via Eclipse, exactly what is going on.  Is Eclipse building some hidden project in some hidden directory (.metadata path??) that emulates a .war file, or does it somehow sync to where my separately installed Tomcat Server is, and somehow use the .war in there?  I have read a number of posts about how this is supposed to work, and many seem contradictory or maybe there are different ways of handling this.  It would help if someone could give a clear understanding of how this is supposed to work, and what I need to do to get Eclipse to recognize code changes.

Now, say if Eclipse does create some hidden directory path with all  your files that emulates a .war file, how do you invoke a build, as it seems that may be the issue here? Somebody else was telling me I need to specify the complied class locations as a runtime path for when executing from within Eclipse.  Confused..

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: You can change the path where the temp deployment happens. For your problem, clean, redeploy should work.

Comment: @Kishore I did try doing a "clean", and I saw that I now received some javadoc info on the method call, but I still wasn't able to get the variable recognized so I can inspect it's value.  How do I perform a "deploy" to Tomcat from within Eclipse when attempting to Debug?  I have been reading that Eclipse by default creates some hidden directory containing you .class files?